# Corona SDK SplashScreen

Tags: lua, coronasdk, splash-screen

I want to be able to create sort of a splash screen when I transition in between my game and menu page, but it seems Corona doesn't support that sort of thing.

Is there some kind of plug-in I could use, or does anyone else have experience doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is not built-in Splashscreen support. You should create one scene that would act as one.